# Asterisk No Audio in Extension

Tags: asterisk

I have an inbound number that I want to connect to my cell. The problem I'm having is that unless I use the music on hold flag, I don't get any audio. 
For example:

```
exten => 1**********,1,Dial(SIP/1**********@flowroute,30,m)
```

The above works great, ot rings on my cell and the call is connected and we can talk.
Now when I remove the music flag or try an ring flag because I need the ringing sound, it connects to my cell, but when I answer, all I get is silence:

```
exten => 1**********,1,Dial(SIP/1**********@flowroute,30)
exten => 1**********,1,Dial(SIP/1**********@flowroute,30,r)
```

Neither of the above works.

Anyone encountered this or have a fix?

[SOLVED]
I added progressinband=yes to sip.conf under the general area. Now when I call with no flags, it rings and there is audio after I pick up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a SIP trace and see which of "180 Ringing" and/or "183 Session Progress" responses that 1**** peer sends you when you dial it without "m" or "r", in what order, and which has SDP. If it differs from cases where you do get ringback, then the problem is the calling peer, and you need to try different `progressinband` settings for that peer (`yes` / `no` / `never`) to work around it.

It's very strange that you get silence after answering when you don't use "m" in Dial(). NAT problem?

Comment: I would guess that the MoH being played keeps the port open in a NAT/ALG somewhere between Asterisk and the cellphone. Without the MoH, the negotiated RTP port is probably being closed before RTP is sent between Asterisk and the phone.

Comment: I added progressinband=yes to my sip.conf general area and in now working. Thanks!